# PHP parsing string to array with regular expressions

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string

I have a string like this:

```
$msg,array('goo','gle'),000,"face",'book',['twi'=>'ter','link'=>'edin']
```

I want to use **preg_match_all** to convert this to an array that could look like this:

```
array(
     0 => $msg,
     1 => array('goo','gle'),
     2 => 000,
     3 => "face",
     4 => 'book',
     5 => ['twi'=>'ter','link'=>'edin']
);
```

> Note that all the values are **string** .

I am not very good at regular expressions, so I have just been unable to create a **Pattern** for this. Multiple preg calls will also do.

Comment: Well, I already answered, but is `['twi'=>'ter','link'=>'edin']` and others a STRING or should they define an actual array?

Comment: No they all should go as string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using `preg_split` with the following regex:

```
$re = "/([a-z]*(?:\\[[^]]*\\]|\\([^()]*\\)),?)|(?<=,)/"; 
$str = "\$msg,array('goo','gle'),000,\"face\",'book',['twi'=>'ter','link'=>'edin']"; 
print_r(preg_split($re, $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

Output of [the sample program](https://ideone.com/dfOQMZ):

```
Array
(
    [0] => $msg,
    [1] => array('goo','gle'),
    [2] => 000,
    [3] => "face",
    [4] => 'book',
    [5] => ['twi'=>'ter','link'=>'edin']
)
```

Comment: this is just awesome! Can recommend me something to learn that level of Regular expressions.

Comment: That level can be achieved with some time... I am using regular expressions for about 6 years, but to tell the truth, I learnt a lot more here, on StackOverflow, in about 3 months. Subscribe to the regex tag, watch for the accepted answers given for high-upvoted questions, look at the favorite questions tagged by regex "gurus" (users with high reputation)... This regex is in part the result of what I read about regex at http://www.rexegg.com/, and partly thanks to @anubhava's answers.

Answer (score 2):

I know you asked for a regular expression solution, however I'm on an `eval()` kick today:

```
eval('$array = array('.$string.');');

print_r($array);
```

Also note that `000` is NOT a string and will be converted to `0`.

Comment: Seems like you have an `evil()` day today :)?